# Qt. interactiing with gui from another thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a library, which works in separate std::thread. This library works as follows. On button click I call library's object method, which starts a longtime task. When calling this method it is possible to provide progress callback, which periodically is called by the library for notification of what is doing at the current moment.

Callback is defined like

`typedef std::function <void (const std::string &message)> Callback;`

I've wrote very-very simple example, describing my case. Here is it:

```
class FakeLibrary
{
    typedef std::function<void (const std::string &str)> Callback;
public:
    FakeLibrary() {}
    void run(Callback callback)
    {
        auto lambda = [this, callback]() {
            callback("blahblah");
        };

        std::thread thread(lambda);
        thread.detach();
    }
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    FakeLibrary *library_obj = new FakeLibrary;
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, library_obj]() {
        library_obj->run([this](const std::string &message) {
            ui->textEdit->append(QString::fromStdString(message));
            qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(message);
        });
    });
}
```

It falls on appending message to textEdit. If i comment this line all is OK, qDebug correctly prints my message.

Also it works correctly if instead of appending message to log in lambda i emit signal and do the appending in corresponding slot:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(this, &MainWindow::append, this, &MainWindow::append_log);
    FakeLibrary *library_obj = new FakeLibrary;
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [this, library_obj]() {
        library_obj->run([this](const std::string &message) {
            emit append(QString::fromStdString(message));
            qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(message);
        });
    });
}

void MainWindow::append_log(const QString &message)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(message);
}
```

So can anybody explain me what is the difference and why it falls in first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library_obj->run([this](const std::string &message) {
    ui->textEdit->append(QString::fromStdString(message));
    qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(message);
});
```

You passed a lambda function which contains operation of GUI object.
should not do out of the main thread.

> As mentioned, each program has one thread when it is started. This
>   thread is called the "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread" in
>   Qt applications). The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and
>   several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary
>   threads. A secondary thread is commonly referred to as a "worker
>   thread" because it is used to offload processing work from the main
>   thread.

The second one actually using:

```
QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, 
                                         PointerToMemberFunction signal, 
                                         const QObject *receiver, 
                                         PointerToMemberFunction method, 
                                         Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect

The default value of the last param is `Qt::AutoConnection`, that makes GUI operation cross thread become possible. The first one directly invoke the function, same as changing the `Qt::ConnectionType` to `Qt::DirectConnection`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the GUI only in the main thread. That's why the first example fails.

The second example works because signal-slot connections can cross thread-boundaries (by posting events to the target object's thread under the hood).

You can read about this in [Qt's threading documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html), especially the parts about thread affinity, and signal-slot connections.